# How Can We Check All Checkbox Are Checked in Gitlab Merge Request Template

Tags: gitlab, merge-request

Gitlab has a merge request template, and we can add a checklist to this merge request template.
I want to enable the merge icon if all checks are completed. The completed task's number is shown on the merge request page.

[image]

Gitlab doesn't support this feature but do you have any idea or something?